# Curl JSON Post with node-libcurl

Tags: node.js, json, curl

I  am using node-libcurl to post a JSON to a URL and receive back a JSON.

I tested the CURL on PHP and it works fine.

The PHP code is the following

```
$data = array('user' => $us, 'pwd' => $cl);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://52.234.214.55:9001/autenticacion/externo');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now I want to make it work on a node route that looks like this:

```
app.post('/login2',function(req,res){

  //formato JSON ACHS
  var cvalue = {
      'user': 'user',
      'pwd': 'pass'
    }

    var curl = new Curl();

    curl.setOpt('URL', 'http://52.234.214.55:9001/autenticacion/externo');
    curl.setOpt('CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST', "POST");
    curl.setOpt('CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS', cvalue);
    curl.setOpt('CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER', true);
    curl.setOpt('CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER', array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen(cvalue)));

curl.on('end', function(statusCode, body, headers) {

    console.info(statusCode);
    console.info('---');
    console.info(body.length);
    console.info('---');
    console.info(this.getInfo( 'TOTAL_TIME'));

    this.close();
});

curl.on('error', curl.close.bind(curl));
curl.perform();

})
```

This does not work I get the following error:

> Unknown option given. First argument must be the option internal id or the option name. You can use the Curl.option constants.
> at Curl.setOpt (C:\Users\Ingolf\workspace\w2_achs2\node_modules\node-libcurl\lib\Curl.js:980:11)
> at C:\Users\Ingolf\workspace\w2_achs2\index.js:130:10

this points to

```
curl.setOpt('CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST', "POST");
```

As suggested and found in documentation I changed it to:

```
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, 'http://52.234.214.55:9001/autenticacion/externo');
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cvalue);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen(cvalue)));
```

this gets the error:

> Unknown option given. First argument must be the option internal id or the option name. You can use the Curl.option constants.
> at Curl.setOpt (C:\Users\Ingolf\workspace\w2_achs2\node_modules\node-libcurl\lib\Curl.js:980:11)
> at C:\Users\Ingolf\workspace\w2_achs2\index.js:131:10

which points to

```
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cvalue);
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `node-libcurl` documentation:
https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/blob/HEAD/api.md#curloption--enum

More specifically, you need to be using the enumerated options rather the cURL compatible options string:

> CURLOPT_URL becomes Curl.option.URL

Try this:

```
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```